# Using nested for loops to create a triangle with asterisks

Tags: java, geometry

using nested for loops statements to draw triangles of "*"s. The number of  "*"s  on the last row is input from the user (valid range: 5 to 21). the out put should look like this:
Sample output:

How many stars/last row (5-21)? 25 
Out of range. Reenter: 7

```
* 
** 
*** 
**** 
***** 
****** 
*******
```

so far this is what i have for the code. I don't know how to get it to look like a triangle. any help would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7_2{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    //declarations
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    int how_many;//num of triangles
    int m; //constant
    int c;//constant
    int rows;//row

    //prompt for input
    System.out.println("Drawing triangles program.");
    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println("How many triangles?");
    how_many=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many stars/last row (5-21)?");
    rows=input.nextInt();
    while(rows<=5||rows>=21){
      System.out.println("Out of range. Reenter: ");
      rows=input.nextInt();
    }
    for(m=1;m<=rows;m++){
      for(c=1;c<=m;c++){
        System.out.println("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: What does your program output?

Comment: If you know [Zethen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2862772/zethen) he may be able to help you.

Comment: I've got to say, Ive seen this homework 3 or 4 times on stack overflow, you have by far got the furthest out of any of them before heading here

Comment: This kind of an error is easy to fix if you learn how to use the debug tools in your ide. Id recommend brushing up on them.

Comment: Richard is right. This post is how all theese questions should look like in the first place... Keep up the good questions!

Answer (score 2):

To center a line, use this:

```
private static String center(String line, int length) {
    StringBuilder newLine = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < (line.length() - length)/2; i++)
        newLine.append(" ");
    }
    newLine.append(line);
    return newLine.toString();
}
```

Also,

```
System.out.println();
```

prints a line break after each string, which is not what you intend.

---

Fixed code:

```
private void printTriangle(int base) {
    StringBuilder currentStars = new StringBuilder();
    for (int currLine = 1; currLine < base; currLine++) {
        currentStars.append("*"); // Don't create a new String, just append a "*" to the old line.
        //if (currLine % 2 == 1)
        //    System.out.println(center(currentStars.toString(), base)); // For centered triangle
        System.out.println(currentStars.toString()); // For non-centered triangle
    }
}
```

Comment: If he doesn't, omit the #center() in the println() call. Still using the StringBuilder will be much better than nested for-loops.

Comment: Ah, I see the magic, nice. (No didn't run it, that is cheating) This is the rare case when not erasing the previous contents/creating a new container object for an iteration is a merit, not a mistake. Will remember it for sure

Comment: @ppeterka66 Haha xD Yeah, this way, only one string is created per line by the #toString(). Saves a lot of OPS i.e. time in a larger scenario

Comment: Maybe you should explain the code in a more direct way, so the folks like me understand the "magic" happening behind it.

Comment: @ppeterka66 Like this?

Comment: Yep, exactly like this

Answer (score 1):

You are using a println statement to print your stars, as such each will be on its own line no matter what

```
System.out.println("*");
```

You want a print statement instead

```
System.out.print("*");
```

Additionally inside the star printing loop you have an extra `System.out.println();` putting a blank line in, that should be outside the inner for loop

```
for(m=1;m<=rows;m++){
  for(c=1;c<=m;c++){
    System.out.println("*"); <-- println always starts a new line, should be print
    System.out.println(); <--- shouldn't be within inner loop
  }
  <--- println() should be here to advance to the next line of stars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`println()` always starts a new line after the output. Try `print` instead and then one `println()` after the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your `for` loop as

```
for (m = 1; m <= rows; m++) {
    for (c = 1; c <= m; c++) {
        // first print the * on the same line
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    // then move to the next line
    System.out.println();
}
```

Notice, that you need to use `System.out.print()` (that does not write a new line `\n` to the output stream) for the asterisks `*` to get printed on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the most efficient and simple way to do it, saves having to call the print/println method hundreds of times when playing with larger pyramids.

```
String out;
for (m = 0; m < rows; m++) {
    out = "";
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
        out+="*";
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Basicly your string is "", and you add a "*" after every time you print it to the next line.